# how to get data from input form in React js by clicking submit button and create a div element that get all data user input. {.map() Multiple states}

Tags: reactjs, user-input, react-forms

I'd like to create div with data getting from user input by clicking btn submit, But I don't know how. I am new in react js.

This is my App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import './RegisterApp.css'
import RegisterApp from './Components/RegisterApp';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RegisterApp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my component file RegisterApp.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function RegisterApp() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Khun Neary')
  const [position, setPosition] = useState('Designer')
  const [list, setList] = useState({name, position})
 
  const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setList(...list, name)
    setList(...list, position)
    console.log(list);
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <form className='form-box' onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <button>Upload Profile</button>
            
            <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder='Name...'
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
           
            <input
            type="text" 
            placeholder='Position...'
            value={position}
            onChange={(e) => setPosition(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div className='register-box'>
          <div className='sub-reg-box'>
              <div className='img-box'></div>
              <div className='detail-box'>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <h4>{position}</h4>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default RegisterApp
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxrBN.png)

I'd like to create div element after I click submit btn and display all the data get from input by user.

Comment: You don't need to "get" the data. You already have it in the variables `name` and `position`.

Answer (score 1):

add  `type="submit"` to button

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

then update the list state

```
 const formSubmit = (e) => { 
    setList( {...list, name, position })  
  }
```

you won't see the update to the `list` immediately since setState in asynchronous. But to check that, you can use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(list)
},[list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "get" the data. You already have it in the variables `name` and `position`. You should create an `onClick` handler for the button that uses these values.

Note that `setList()` is misnamed. You should use an object here. In fact, you can get rid of `list` and `setList` because you already have `name`, `setName`, `position` and `setPosition`. You don't need both.